# Limiting/Specifying Authentication Schemes Available per Client Application in IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

Can you specify the available authentication schemes or force a client application to use a specific authentication scheme?

I see the Client Option, `EnableLocalLogin` that can be set to false in the Client Config. It would be nice to limit the available external authentication options or specify the authentication scheme to be used by client application.

Answer (score 0):

The [IdentityProviderRestrictions property](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/stable/reference/client.html) on the Client configuration is used to control this.